# Trying to display key of object in array to table

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

this feels like a super simple question I thought I knew the solution but just can't figure out why it's not working.

I am trying to display records from Firestore in a table.
Some of the fields go in fine into the table, but one of the fields which is made up of an
array of objects is giving me problems, the object contains childName, childAge & childId. I am trying to display childName.

I just want to display the child name of the first Children object.

but I keep getting the error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

```
<TableBody>
        {forms.map(row => (
          <TableRow key={row.id}>

             //the TableCell below where I am trying to display childName
            <TableCell component={"th"} scope={"row"}>
              {row.children[0].childName}
            </TableCell>

            <TableCell>{row.timeIn}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{row.timeOut}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{row.parentName}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{row.shoeBoxNumber}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        ))}
      </TableBody>
```

Below is the full error screenshot:
[image: error image]

Below is my state, I'm using React hooks:
[image: state image]

Comment: do you want to show only 1st object

Comment: you can loop over it. it's saying cannot read property ' 0 ' of undefined is row.children[0] in undefined add a check to check it's value

Comment: Yes, just the first object of Children. Ill update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add validation: if array is not empty:
{row.children && row.children.length && row.children[0].childName}

```
<TableBody>
        {forms.map(row => (
          <TableRow key={row.id}>

             //the TableCell below where I am trying to display childName
            <TableCell component={"th"} scope={"row"}>
              {row.children && row.children.length && row.children[0].childName}
            </TableCell>

            <TableCell>{row.timeIn}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{row.timeOut}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{row.parentName}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{row.shoeBoxNumber}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        ))}
      </TableBody>
```

Comment: Yes, That did the trick. I had thought about doing validation, thinking that the data might not have arrived yet, which would give me an empty array, but then saw that the other data was displaying so I thought that was not the problem, and it was just how I trying to access the data. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

you can add a validation to check if you array exist with data

```
<TableBody>
        {forms.map((row)=> (
          <TableRow key={row.id}>

             //the TableCell below where I am trying to display childName
           if(row.children[0]){
             return (
              <TableCell component={"th"} scope={"row"}>
              {row.children[0].childName}
              </TableCell>
              )
            }

            <TableCell>{row.timeIn}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{row.timeOut}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{row.parentName}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{row.shoeBoxNumber}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        ))}
      </TableBody>
```

Comment: Code without explanation is rarely upvoted. Also, you've changed the data that are displayed in the first element from the first child's `childName` to the current child's `childName`. That probably warrants some explanation as well...